# Failed to send the transaction successfully to the order status: SERVICE UNAVAILABLE

Tags: apache-kafka, hyperledger-fabric, devops, hyperledger

I am using kakfa orderer service for hyperledger fabric 1.4. while updating chaincode or making any puutState call i am getting error message stated as `Failed to send the transaction successfully to the order status: SERVICE UNAVAILABLE`. while checking zoopeker and kafka node it seems like kafka nodes are not able to talk to each other.

[kakfa & zookeeper logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vj4ZS.png)

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide more info about the topology of the zookeeper-kafka cluster?

Did you use docker to deploy the zk cluster? If so, you can refer to this file.
https://github.com/whchengaa/hyperledger-fabric-technical-tutorial/blob/cross-machine-hosts-file/balance-transfer/artifacts/docker-compose-kafka.yaml

Remember to specify the IP address of the other zookeeper nodes in the hosts file which is mounted to /etc/hosts of that zookeeper node.

Make sure the port number of zookeeper nodes listed in ZOO_SERVERS environment variables are correct.

Comment: #ORDERER LOGS2020-09-08 07:51:57.146 UTC [common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 325 [channel: claimschannel] Rejecting deliver request for 10.0.0.247:40528 because of consenter erro

Comment: @RohitRoy Could show the details of the docker-compose file for zookeeper-kafka cluster deployment (or other implementation style)?

Comment: [orderer.common.server] Deliver -> DEBU 4c4 Starting new Deliver handler
[common.deliver] Handle -> DEBU 4c5 Starting new deliver loop for 10.0.0.*:34322
[common.deliver] Handle -> DEBU 4c6 Attempting to read seek info message from 10.0.0.*:34322
[common.deliver] deliverBlocks -> WARN 4c7 [channel: channel_name] Rejecting deliver request for 10.0.0.*:34322 because of consenter error
[orderer.common.server] func1 -> DEBU 4c8 Closing Deliver stream

Comment: [blocksProvider] DeliverBlocks -> WARN 4979 [channel_name] Got error &{SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE}
[ConnProducer] DisableEndpoint -> WARN 497a Only 1 endpoint remained, will not black-list it

Comment: This network was working fine three days ago thats why i don't think is a configuration issue.

Comment: @RohitRoy u mean zk-kafka cluster didn't show any error and worked fine three days ago?